# Django zip multiple PDF files generated with xhtml2pdf

Tags: django, zip, xhtml2pdf

I am successfully using `xhtml2pdf` to generate a `PDF` file for download.

What I would now like to achieve is the ability to generate multiple (separate) `PDF` files for download. I'm guessing that the best way to achieve this is to zip the `PDF`'s, but I'm at a loss at how to go about achieving this. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

My function for rendering to `PDF` is:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}): 
    template =   get_template(template_src) 
    html = template.render(context_dict) 
    result = BytesIO() 
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")),result, link_callback=link_callback) 
    if not pdf.err: 
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf') 

    return None
```

My view for generating the single `PDF` file is:

```
class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        context = { 'date':date }
        pdf = render_to_pdf('pdf/my_first_file.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "First_File.pdf"
            content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response

        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

The other files I would like to render as `PDF` as part of the `zip` download are all in the `pdf/` folder. There will be a maximum of 12 of these. The context differs for each:

```
pdf/my_second_file.html
pdf/my_third_file.html
...
```

Any guidance that can be provided will be much appreciated!